# Silex - Code coverage from functional test

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, functional-testing, silex

I would like to generate code coverage from functional testing in Silex App via PHPUnit. I created [sandbox](https://github.com/o5/silex-code-coverage) where you could reproduce.

The question is: Why `Controller::indexAction()` method is marked as `Not Executed` code in code coverage report?

[image: code coverage]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No time for testing.
What i have seen:

You are setting your test array for the first test in `app.php`

```
return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse(['foo' => 'bar']);
```

Why? And did the test fail if you remove that? Maybe here the `Controller` isn't tested.

Then you are testing the 2 methods not in the same way.

Maybe that leads to the solution of the problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm ... :D Look at time https://github.com/o5/silex-code-coverage/commit/51761a36b361802590d1662b9250258b74d6342a

Comment: I am glad to help :)